Однократная инициализация атрибута у класса C#
В моем приложении имеются сообщения, которые должны отправляться/приниматься по сети. Для идентификации этих сообщений используется хэш от его структуры данных. Структура данных постоянная и представлена в виде строки. Хэш этой строки служит идентификатором этого сообщения.
Появилась идея прописывать структуру данных в атрибуте класса и в результате получился вот такой код:
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class FooAttribute : Attribute
{
    public byte[] Hash { get; }
    public FooAttribute(string value)
    {
        Hash = SHA256.HashData(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value));
        Console.WriteLine($"Init attribute with param '{value}'");
    }
}

[Foo(nameof(TestClass))]
public class TestClass
{
    public byte[] Hash => GetType().GetCustomAttribute<FooAttribute>()!.Hash;
}

У меня было представление, что эти атрибуты создаются однократно и будут храниться в типе (класс Type) в виде синглтон объектов, но оказалось это не так. При каждой попытке получить доступ к атрибуту, создается его новый экземпляр.
На практике результат работы приложения выглядит вот так:
TestClass testClass = new();
Type typeOfTestClass = typeof(TestClass);

Console.WriteLine($"Hash of class is {testClass.Hash}");
Console.WriteLine($"Hash of class is {testClass.Hash}");
Console.WriteLine($"Hash of class is {typeOfTestClass.GetCustomAttribute<FooAttribute>()!.Hash}");
Console.WriteLine($"Hash of class is {typeOfTestClass.GetCustomAttribute<FooAttribute>()!.Hash}");

// Init attribute with param 'TestClass'
// Hash of class is System.Byte[]
// Init attribute with param 'TestClass'
// Hash of class is System.Byte[]
// Init attribute with param 'TestClass'
// Hash of class is System.Byte[]
// Init attribute with param 'TestClass'
// Hash of class is System.Byte[]

Идея этого решения заключалась в том, чтобы высчитывать хэш для класса один раз при его первичной инициализации и не тратить на это ресурсы при последующих.
Возможно ли добиться такого поведения атрибутов? Или такое невозможно и придется прибегать к статическим свойствам класса?

как ты проверял, что При каждой попытке получить доступ к атрибуту, создается его новый экземпляр?

@Grundy с помощью Console.WriteLine. В моем вопросе примеры кода и результат его работы есть.

Да, пропустил что это в конструкторе атрибута было

атрибут инстанциируется при получении атрибута, например с помощью GetCustomAttribute

Как вариант, сделать dictionary и если уже есть вернуть из кэша.

Поскольку проблема с атрибутами вторична, я предлагаю решение для первичной проблемы автора - сделать перманентный хэш названия класса.
Вариант с использованием CRTP:
public class Item<TSelf> where TSelf : Item<TSelf> {
    public static readonly byte[] Hash;
    static Item() {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(TSelf).FullName);
        Hash = SHA256.HashData(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(typeof(TSelf).FullName));
    }
}

public class TestClass1 : Item<TestClass1> { }

public class TestClass2 : Item<TestClass2> { }

internal static class Program {
    static string Ba2String(this byte[] ba) => String.Join("; ", ba);
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine(TestClass1.Hash.Ba2String());
        Console.WriteLine(TestClass2.Hash.Ba2String());
        Console.WriteLine(TestClass1.Hash.Ba2String());
        Console.WriteLine(TestClass2.Hash.Ba2String());
    }
}

-->

ConsoleApp1.TestClass1
191; 234; 69; 62; 236; 166; 234; 250; 228; 18; 48; 95; 52; 40; 188; 98; 181; 23; 84; 252; 138; 60; 54; 106; 194; 15; 254; 197; 223; 69; 250; 251
ConsoleApp1.TestClass2
109; 197; 218; 171; 226; 154; 4; 64; 126; 185; 184; 121; 163; 138; 9; 224; 238; 147; 44; 163; 91; 63; 225; 24; 109; 244; 156; 80; 132; 28; 23; 159
191; 234; 69; 62; 236; 166; 234; 250; 228; 18; 48; 95; 52; 40; 188; 98; 181; 23; 84; 252; 138; 60; 54; 106; 194; 15; 254; 197; 223; 69; 250; 251
109; 197; 218; 171; 226; 154; 4; 64; 126; 185; 184; 121; 163; 138; 9; 224; 238; 147; 44; 163; 91; 63; 225; 24; 109; 244; 156; 80; 132; 28; 23; 159


readonly нужно добавить

@evo "readonly нужно добавить" - таки да

Непонятно, почему ответ на вопрос, который получил 1 голос, не получил ни одного!

Никто не обязан ставить стрелку вверх если таковое решение не считается для человека полезным, если бы для меня это было новостью, или этот ответ был полезен для меня, пожалуйста =)
